# Want to have an event handler for the browser's back button with next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am having a modal which while opening pushes a hash to url `example.com/#modal`, on browser back button click, I want to recognise that event so that I can toggle the state of modal. the point is, since Im using it with next.js (server side rendering), I will not be having access to window object (correct me if I am wrong). so I need an alternate way to handle the event of browser back button.

Comment: did you fixed it?

Answer (score 25):

You can use `next/router`'s [`beforePopState`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerbeforepopstate) to act on changes to the session history navigation (back/forward actions), and make sure it'll only happen when leaving the current page.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    router.beforePopState(({ as }) => {
        if (as !== router.asPath) {
            // Will run when leaving the current page; on back/forward actions
            // Add your logic here, like toggling the modal state
        }
        return true;
    });

    return () => {
        router.beforePopState(() => true);
    };
}, [router]); // Add any state variables to dependencies array if needed.
```

Comment: This is a good solution but you should be comparing `as` (another prop on the callback object) to `router.asPath`, not `url`. The url maybe different even on the same page

Comment: @nathajamal Yes, that's a good point. Since `asPath` is the path shown in the browser it only makes sense that it should be compared to the `as` prop. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Why does this need to be in a `useEffect` hook?  @juliomalves

Comment: @SunnyPatel Because adding a listener to the `beforePopState` event of `next/router` should occur on the client-side.

Comment: @juliomalves thank you for this! What if you wanted the useEffect to only run on back/foward and arriving at the page? This would be for the use case of syncing filter/sort/pagination state with the URL.

Comment: this still change the url in the browser

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing Of course it does. What in this answer leads you to believe that it wouldn't?

Comment: Why do we need the cleanup function to also return true?

Comment: @milesmeow Setting the callback function to return true resets it to it's default behaviour.

Comment: When function detects browsers back action, how to prevent from going back while modal is opened? @juliomalves

Comment: @Dejan Use `return false` in the condition where the modal is handled.

Comment: @juliomalves I've tried, it seems like it doesn't work, it should "disable" go back action if I return false in the condition where my modal is handled? Also I have another pitfall, when I click on browsers go back button, I got modal opened as expected but my url is changed immediately it should be the same until I confirm that action via modal. So point is to don't go back and don't change url until action is confirmed from modal. Any suggestion?

Comment: You need the `return false` if the condition inside the `router.beforePopState` callback.

Comment: I've posted above my issue and solution, tnx for response. @juliomalves

Answer (score 3):

Fantastic answer by @juliomalves. However, we need to handle URLs properly. Once you return false from `router.beforePopState` handler, page will not be updated. However, url is changed. And this is not what we want. So, it has to be copleted as per following code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    router.beforePopState(({ as }) => {
        const currentPath = router.asPath; 
        if (as !== currentPath) {
            // Will run when leaving the current page; on back/forward actions
            // Add your logic here, like toggling the modal state
            // for example           
            if(confirm("Are you sure?") return true;
            else {
               window.history.pushState(null, "", currentPath);
               return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });

    return () => {
        router.beforePopState(() => true);
    };
}, [router]); // Add any state variables to dependencies array if needed.
```

Comment: This code really work .But How can I display Default Leave Prompt like Tiktok upload Page in Desktop Browser . Not confirm box but Leave Prompt .

Answer (score 2):

in NextJs we can use beforePopState function and do what we want such close modal or show a modal or check the back address and decide what to do

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60702584/4717739

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69560739/4717739

Answer (score 1):

@Summy I hope your issue is resolved by now. If not you can try this for the browser back button:-
[Next.js + React Go back to the previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843119/next-js-react-go-back-to-the-previous-page?answertab=active#tab-top)
If you want to use hashbang URLs you can't use SSR, since /# and /#/one is the same route server-side, so there is no way for the server to know what to render, it will need to send a basic template and let the client fill it, in that case, I think using CRA or Parcel with React Router and its HashRouter is a better option, that way you will have a single index.html and let the client decide what to render.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried above solution but unfortunately didn't work for me. I've managed to overcome given issues for following scenario: Open modal on browsers "go back" action. I had problem when I click on back button, I was getting opened modal but current url was changed to the previous url.

```
export default function BrowserGoBackAction() {


const [showGoBackDialog, setShowGoBackDialog] = useState(false);

  const router = useRouter();

  async function OpenGoBackDialog() {
    setShowGoBackDialog(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    router.beforePopState(({ as }) => {
      //   Detect browsers go back action
      if (as !== router.asPath) {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, router.asPath);
        OpenGoBackDialog();
      }
    });
  });

  function goToPreviousPage() {
    router.beforePopState(() => true);
    return router.back();
  }

  function onCancel() {
    setShowGoBackDialog(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the above solution is not working for my next js application.I found a different way to handle this issue although it is using the hash which will be a unique modalId and we will monitor the hash change via router.asPath and close the modal accordingly.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export const useRestrictModalNavigation = (
    show: boolean,
    onHashRemoved?: () => void
) => {
const router = useRouter();
const setModalHash = (modalId: string) => {
    window.history.pushState({}, '', `#${modalId}`);
};

const handleClose = () => {
    if (onHashRemoved) onHashRemoved();
    clearModalHash();
};
useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
        setModalHash('modal');
    } else {
        clearModalHash();
    }
}, [show]);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleHashChange = () => {
        const { hash } = window.location;
        console.log('Hash changed:', hash);
        if (!hash) if (onHashRemoved) onHashRemoved();
    };

    window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);
    };
}, [router.asPath]);

    return { handleClose };
};

const clearModalHash = () => {
    const { protocol, host, pathname, search } = window.location;
    const newUrl = `${protocol}//${host}${pathname}${search}`;
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, newUrl);
};
```