# Detect when a user leaves page in Next JS

Tags: next.js

I would like to detect when the user leaves the page Next JS. I count 3 ways of leaving a page:

1. by clicking on a link
2. by doing an action that triggers router.back, router.push, etc...
3. by closing the tab (i.e. when beforeunload event is fired

Being able to detect when a page is leaved is very helpful for example, alerting the user some changes have not been saved yet.

I would like something like:

```
router.beforeLeavingPage(() => {
    // my callback
})
```

Comment: You can use the `beforePopState` event to detect changes to the session history navigation as suggested in [Want to have an event handler for the browser's back button with next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932918/want-to-have-an-event-handler-for-the-browsers-back-button-with-next-js). This covers both your point **1.** and **2.**.

Answer (score 19):

I use 'next/router' like [Next.js page](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage-6) to disconnect a socket

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function MyPage() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const exitingFunction = () => {
      console.log("exiting...");
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", exitingFunction);

    return () => {
      console.log("unmounting component...");
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", exitingFunction);
    };
  }, []);

  return <>My Page</>;
}
```

Comment: Does this work when a user closes the tab? Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: How can we do this on NextJS 13?

Comment: Doesn't work with Next JS 14 - router.events has been replaced - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-events

Answer (score 9):

`router.beforePopState` is great for browser back button but not for `<Link>`s on the page.

Solution found here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2694#issuecomment-732990201

> ... Here is a version with this approach, for anyone who gets to this page
> looking for another solution. Note, I have adapted it a bit further
> for my requirements.
>
> ```
> // prompt the user if they try and leave with unsaved changes  
> useEffect(() => {
>   const warningText =
>     'You have unsaved changes - are you sure you wish to leave this page?';
>   const handleWindowClose = (e: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
>     if (!unsavedChanges) return;
>     e.preventDefault();
>     return (e.returnValue = warningText);
>   };
>   const handleBrowseAway = () => {
>     if (!unsavedChanges) return;
>     if (window.confirm(warningText)) return;
>     router.events.emit('routeChangeError');
>     throw 'routeChange aborted.';
>   };
>   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);
>   router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleBrowseAway);
>   return () => {
>     window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);
>     router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleBrowseAway);
>   };
> }, [unsavedChanges]);
> ```
>
> So far, it seems to work pretty reliably.

Alternatively you can add an `onClick` to all the `<Link>`s yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Browsers heavily restrict permissions and features but this works:

- `window.confirm`: for next.js router event
- `beforeunload`: for broswer reload, closing tab or navigating away

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const unsavedChanges = true
  const warningText =
    'You have unsaved changes - are you sure you wish to leave this page?'

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowClose = (e) => {
      if (!unsavedChanges) return
      e.preventDefault()
      return (e.returnValue = warningText)
    }
    const handleBrowseAway = () => {
      if (!unsavedChanges) return
      if (window.confirm(warningText)) return
      router.events.emit('routeChangeError')
      throw 'routeChange aborted.'
    }
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose)
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleBrowseAway)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose)
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleBrowseAway)
    }
  }, [unsavedChanges])

}
export default MyComponent
```

Credit to this [article](https://codeutility.org/reactjs-detect-when-a-user-leaves-page-in-next-js-stack-overflow/)

Comment: I freaked out when I saw this ‘ will be heavily restricted’ thought it was a mail from stackoverflow

Comment:  Got this from you too on GitHub https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/9662#discussioncomment-3816423

Comment: K well regardless hopefully this solution has helped answer your original question  

Comment: Thank you for this code. What's the purpose of `router.events.emit('routeChangeError')`? It seems to work well without that line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `router.beforePopState` [check here for examples](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerbeforepopstate)

Comment: Here's a practical example on how to use the `beforePopState` event to detect back/forward actions: [Want to have an event handler for the browser's back button with next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69569682/1870780).

Answer (score 4):

I saw two things when coding it :

- Knowing when nextjs router would be activated
- Knowing when specific browser event would happen

I did a hook that way. It triggers if next router is used, or if there is a classic browser event (closing tab, refreshing)

```
import SingletonRouter, { Router } from 'next/router';

export function usePreventUserFromErasingContent(shouldPreventLeaving) {
  const stringToDisplay = 'Do you want to save before leaving the page ?';

  useEffect(() => {
    // Prevents tab quit / tab refresh
    if (shouldPreventLeaving) {
      // Adding window alert if the shop quits without saving
      window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return stringToDisplay;
      };
    } else {
      window.onbeforeunload = () => {};
    }

    if (shouldPreventLeaving) {
      // Prevents next routing
      SingletonRouter.router.change = (...args) => {
        if (confirm(stringToDisplay)) {
          return Router.prototype.change.apply(SingletonRouter.router, args);
        } else {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(false));
        }
      };
    }
    return () => {
      delete SingletonRouter.router.change;
    };
  }, [shouldPreventLeaving]);
}
```

You just have to call your hook in the component you want to cover :

```js
usePreventUserFromErasingContent(isThereModificationNotSaved);
```

This a boolean I created with useState and edit when needed. This way, it only triggers when needed.

Comment: This works in my use case though an error will thrown for .change method in Typescript bec. SingletonRouter.router.change is a private method inside next/router

Answer (score 3):

You can use default [web api's eventhandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) in your react page or component.

```
if (process.browser) {
  window.onbeforeunload = () => {
    // your callback
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will always work,  because SSR will give you undefined when you use the window object

Comment: thats why you need to check `process.browser`, to make sure the code below works only in client side.

Comment: process.browser is deprecated. We can use `typeof window !== undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me in next-router / react-FC

1. add router event handler
2. add onBeforeUnload event handler
3. unload them when component unmounted

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2476#issuecomment-563190607

Answer (score 1):

### Intercept route changes at the NextJS app router mode

Demo：[[codeSondbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/next-block-leaving-yf9nlq?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9a000b3b6lujkvkri7%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900023b6l4kn66bas%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900083b6lm7e16teb%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh99000a3b6lqm95cmz6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq1ovh9900023b6l4kn66bas%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900023b6l4kn66bas%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1p4cpn00023b6ld60iy8s9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A4%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A4%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fform.css%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq1p4cpn00023b6ld60iy8s9%2522%257D%252C%2522clq1ovh99000a3b6lqm95cmz6%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900093b6l2s8mq53w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fproxy%252Fstore%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh99000a3b6lqm95cmz6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900093b6l2s8mq53w%2522%257D%252C%2522clq1ovh9900083b6lm7e16teb%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900033b6lp2vrvqp7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900043b6ll8bpphgd%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900053b6lxnemchtd%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900063b6lqbse2rr4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522lint%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900073b6lobmjoxn5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522install%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900083b6lm7e16teb%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq1ovh9900033b6lp2vrvqp7%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)]

Demo video: https://github.com/cgfeel/next.v2/assets/578141/fe1e7f24-054a-4f56-892c-5345ac177a75

source code: https://github.com/cgfeel/next.v2/tree/master/routing-file/src/app/leaving/proxy

Use this Provider in your layout at the app root directory：https://github.com/cgfeel/next.v2/blob/master/routing-file/src/components/proxyProvider/index.tsx

```
'use client'

import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import Script from "next/script";
import { FC, PropsWithChildren, createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ProxyContext = createContext<ProxyInstance>([undefined, () => {}]);

const ProxyProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren<{}>> = ({ children }) => {
    const [tips, setTips] = useState<string|undefined>();
    const msg = tips === undefined ? tips : (tips||'Are you sure want to leave this page?');

    const pathname = usePathname();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();

    const url = [pathname, searchParams].filter(i => i).join('?');
    useEffect(() => {
        setTips(undefined);
    }, [url, setTips]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
            if (msg === undefined) return msg;
            
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = msg;
            
            return msg;
        };

        const script = document.getElementById('proxy-script');
        if (script) {
            script.dataset.msg = msg||'';
            script.dataset.href = location.href;
        }

        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
        }
    }, [msg]);

    return (
        <ProxyContext.Provider
            value={[msg, setTips]}
        >
            <Script
                strategy="afterInteractive"
                id="proxy-script"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `(() => {
                        const originalPushState = history.pushState.bind(history);
                        let currentPoint = 0;
                        let point = 0;
                        window.history.pushState = function(state, title, url) {
                            state.point = ++point;
                            currentPoint = point;
                            originalPushState(state, title, url);
                        };
                        const originalReplaceState = history.replaceState.bind(history);
                        window.history.replaceState = function(state, title, url) {
                            state.point = currentPoint;
                            originalReplaceState(state, title, url);
                        };
                        window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
                            const { state: nextState } = event;
                            const isback = currentPoint > nextState.point;

                            currentPoint = nextState.point;

                            const script = document.getElementById('proxy-script');
                            if (!script || location.href === script.dataset.href) return;

                            const msg = script.dataset.msg||'';
                            const confirm = msg == '' ? true : window.confirm(msg);
                            if (!confirm) {
                                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                isback ? history.forward() : history.back();
                            }
                        });
                    })()`,
                }}
            ></Script>
            {children}
        </ProxyContext.Provider>
    );
};

export type ProxyInstance = [
    string|undefined, (tips?: string) => void
]

export { ProxyContext };

export default ProxyProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a medium article [Prevent Route Changes and Unsaved Data Loss in Next.js](https://betterprogramming.pub/prevent-route-changes-and-unsaved-data-loss-in-next-js-f93622d73791). Here is the full code:

```
import SingletonRouter, { Router } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const defaultConfirmationDialog = async (msg?: string) => window.confirm(msg);

/**
 * React Hook
 */
export const useLeavePageConfirmation = (
  shouldPreventLeaving: boolean,
  message: string = 'Changes you made may not be saved.',
  confirmationDialog: (msg?: string) => Promise<boolean> = defaultConfirmationDialog
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // @ts-ignore because "change" is private in Next.js
    if (!SingletonRouter.router?.change) {
      return;
    }

    // @ts-ignore because "change" is private in Next.js
    const originalChangeFunction = SingletonRouter.router.change;
    const originalOnBeforeUnloadFunction = window.onbeforeunload;

    /*
     * Modifying the window.onbeforeunload event stops the browser tab/window from
     * being closed or refreshed. Since it is not possible to alter the close or reload
     * alert message, an empty string is passed to trigger the alert and avoid confusion
     * about the option to modify the message.
     */
    if (shouldPreventLeaving) {
      window.onbeforeunload = () => '';
    } else {
      window.onbeforeunload = originalOnBeforeUnloadFunction;
    }

    /*
     * Overriding the router.change function blocks Next.js route navigations
     * and disables the browser's back and forward buttons. This opens up the
     * possibility to use the window.confirm alert instead.
     */
    if (shouldPreventLeaving) {
      // @ts-ignore because "change" is private in Next.js
      SingletonRouter.router.change = async (...args) => {
        const [historyMethod, , as] = args;
        // @ts-ignore because "state" is private in Next.js
        const currentUrl = SingletonRouter.router?.state.asPath.split('?')[0];
        const changedUrl = as.split('?')[0];
        const hasNavigatedAwayFromPage = currentUrl !== changedUrl;
        const wasBackOrForwardBrowserButtonClicked = historyMethod === 'replaceState';
        let confirmed = false;

        if (hasNavigatedAwayFromPage) {
          confirmed = await confirmationDialog(message);
        }

        if (confirmed) {
          // @ts-ignore because "change" is private in Next.js
          Router.prototype.change.apply(SingletonRouter.router, args);
        } else if (wasBackOrForwardBrowserButtonClicked && hasNavigatedAwayFromPage) {
          /*
           * The URL changes even if the user clicks "false" to navigate away from the page.
           * It is necessary to update it to reflect the current URL.
           */
          // @ts-ignore because "state" is private in Next.js
          await SingletonRouter.router?.push(SingletonRouter.router?.state.asPath);

          /*
           * @todo
           *   I attempted to determine if the user clicked the forward or back button on the browser,
           *   but was unable to find a solution after several hours of effort. As a result, I temporarily
           *   hardcoded it to assume the back button was clicked, since that is the most common scenario.
           *   However, this may cause issues with the URL if the forward button is actually clicked.
           *   I hope that a solution can be found in the future.
           */
          const browserDirection = 'back';

          browserDirection === 'back'
            ? history.go(1) // back button
            : history.go(-1); // forward button
        }
      };
    }

    /*
     * When the component is unmounted, the original change function is assigned back.
     */
    return () => {
      // @ts-ignore because "change" is private in Next.js
      SingletonRouter.router.change = originalChangeFunction;
      window.onbeforeunload = originalOnBeforeUnloadFunction;
    };
  }, [shouldPreventLeaving, message, confirmationDialog]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## updated solution 2023

This is a solution for the pages directory (not tested on app!)

How it works:

1. Uses router change events - to track when changing page without refresh
2. Uses window.onbeforeunload event - to track when user closed the tab or refreshed the page

Code:

Please use this code in the _app.js file. You can also put it in a specific page but then it won't execute on all the pages. You can also make a seperate file for this and import it wherever needed.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const exitingFunction = async () => {
      console.log("exiting...");
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", exitingFunction);
    window.onbeforeunload = exitingFunction;

    return () => {
      console.log("unmounting component...");
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", exitingFunction);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [react-use npm package](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/HEAD/docs/useBeforeUnload.md)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Router from "next/router";
import { useBeforeUnload } from "react-use";

export const useLeavePageConfirm = (
  isConfirm = true,
  message = "Are you sure want to leave this page?"
) => {
  useBeforeUnload(isConfirm, message);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      if (isConfirm && !window.confirm(message)) {
        throw "Route Canceled";
      }
    };

    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handler);

    return () => {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handler);
    };
  }, [isConfirm, message]);
};
```

Comment: This is not an answer