# How to handle needing a return value from a Confirm Dialog react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, dialog

I'm trying to implement a "Are you sure?" confirmation dialog when someone tries to leave a react next.js page without saving the data entered in a form.
This functionality already works with the help of this hook from
[Robert S (codeBelt)](https://betterprogramming.pub/prevent-route-changes-and-unsaved-data-loss-in-next-js-f93622d73791)<sup>1</sup>:

```js
import SingletonRouter, { Router } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const defaultConfirmationDialog = async (msg) => window.confirm(msg);

export const useLeavePageConfirmation = (
  shouldPreventLeaving,
  message = "Changes you made may not be saved.",
  confirmationDialog = defaultConfirmationDialog
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!SingletonRouter.router?.change) {
      return;
    }

    const originalChangeFunction = SingletonRouter.router.change;
    const originalOnBeforeUnloadFunction = window.onbeforeunload;

    if (shouldPreventLeaving) {
      window.onbeforeunload = () => "";
    } else {
      window.onbeforeunload = originalOnBeforeUnloadFunction;
    }

    if (shouldPreventLeaving) {
      SingletonRouter.router.change = async (...args) => {
        const [historyMethod, , as] = args;
        const currentUrl = SingletonRouter.router?.state.asPath.split("?")[0];
        const changedUrl = as.split("?")[0];
        const hasNavigatedAwayFromPage = currentUrl !== changedUrl;
        const wasBackOrForwardBrowserButtonClicked =
          historyMethod === "replaceState";
        let confirmed = false;

        if (hasNavigatedAwayFromPage) {
          confirmed = await confirmationDialog(message);
        }

        if (confirmed) {
          Router.prototype.change.apply(SingletonRouter.router, args);
        } else if (
          wasBackOrForwardBrowserButtonClicked &&
          hasNavigatedAwayFromPage
        ) {
          await SingletonRouter.router?.push(
            SingletonRouter.router?.state.asPath
          );
          const browserDirection = "back";

          browserDirection === "back"
            ? history.go(1) // back button
            : history.go(-1); // forward button
        }
      };
    }

    return () => {
      SingletonRouter.router.change = originalChangeFunction;
      window.onbeforeunload = originalOnBeforeUnloadFunction;
    };
  }, [shouldPreventLeaving, message, confirmationDialog]);
};
```

But this uses the browser confirm dialog. I would prefer to use the [MUI dialog](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/), since our site uses Material UI.

The MUI dialog works fine on other parts of the site, but I struggle combining the two things.

The `useLeavePageConfirmation` hook is waiting for a return value at

```js
confirmed = await confirmationDialog(message);
```

Below is my attempt so far:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import NextLink from "next/link";
import { useLeavePageConfirmation } from "@/hooks/useLeavePageConfirmation";

import {
  FormControlLabel,
  Switch,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  Button,
  Link,
} from "@mui/material";
export const ConfirmDialog = ({ dialogState }) => {
  return (
    <Dialog open={dialogState.open} onClose={dialogState.handleCancel}>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText>{dialogState.question}</DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button autoFocus onClick={dialogState.handleCancel}>
          {dialogState.cancelText || "Cancel"}
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={dialogState.handleConfirm}>
          {dialogState.confirmText || "Yes"}
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

function SimplePage() {
  const [dialogState, setDialogState] = useState({
    open: false,
    question: "",
  });
  const handleCloseDialog = () =>
    setDialogState((dialog) => {
      return { ...dialog, open: false };
    });

  const [changesOnPage, setChangesOnPage] = useState(true);

  const customizedDialog = async (msg) => {
    setDialogState({
      ...dialogState,
      question: "Are you sure?",
      open: true,
      handleConfirm: async () => {
        // do something to set confirmationValue true
      },
      handleCancel: aysnc () => {
        // do something to set confirmationValue false
        handleCloseDialog()
      }
    })

    return confirmationValue;
  };

  useLeavePageConfirmation(changesOnPage, "Custom Message", customizedDialog);

  return (
    <>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
            checked={changesOnPage}
            onChange={() => setChangesOnPage((changes) => !changes)}
            name="changed"
          />
        }
        label="Changes on page"
      />
      {changesOnPage ? <p>changed</p> : <p>not changed</p>}
      <ConfirmDialog dialogState={dialogState} />
      <NextLink href={"../"}>leave</NextLink>
    </>
  );
}

export default SimplePage;
```

This feels wrong, but I had no better approach yet. Is there a way to get a return value for `customizedDialog`? I guess I need in some way a Promise. Or maybe change the code inside of `useLeavePageConfirmation` to not expect a return value, but check for a state value?

---

### Update

here is a codesandbox with the example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-confirm-dialog-lfldtn

---

<sup>1</sup> also mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75959073/1786528)