# How to tell if a page was loaded as the result of a back button press in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I need to load some data when a route loads as the result of a back button press using NextJS. How can I tell if a route / page was loaded as a result of the user pressing the back button on the browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to have an event handler for the browser's back button with next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932918/want-to-have-an-event-handler-for-the-browsers-back-button-with-next-js)

Answer (score 2):

The [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) object provided by the browser won't tell you if someone used the back button. It and next/router and next/link are used for manipulating paths, not necessarily tracking history. For that, you probably need to manually track the user on your site, perhaps using cookies, `window.localStorage`, or something server-side.

The events exposed by [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents) (such as all the `routeChange*` and `beforeHistoryChange` events) might be useful.