# In Next.js is there a way to determine if if scrollRestoration was used, or even if the back button was used?

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

I am using the `scrollRestoration` feature of Next.js to restore the page position when a back button is pressed.  The problem, is that it doesn't restore the horizontal scroll position of the carousels on that page.  So I have created my own session variables to track the position of each carousel and restore them on page load.  The problem, is that I ONLY want to restore these scroll positions if the back/forward button was pressed.  If there is an indicator that `scrollRestoration` was used on the page I could use that, otherwise, if there is an indication that the page was visited using the forward/back buttons that would also solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding handling back/forward actions, does this help: [Want to have an event handler for the browser's back button with next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932918/want-to-have-an-event-handler-for-the-browsers-back-button-with-next-js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have figured out how to determine if scrollRestoration is set for a page.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const hasScrollHistory = sessionStorage.getItem(`__next_scroll_${window.history.state.idx}`);
    if (hasScrollHistory) {
        // do your restore logic here
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never done this but my instinct would be:

- Make a wrapper component, expose the [next/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) in your component
- Set up an `useEffect` that updates on [router.pathName](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) changes
- Set up a condition in the effect that watches [History.back()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back)

That kind of goes around the framework, but it doesn't look like Next exposes what you're looking for.