# Browser back button to go back to specific route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am on a certain link when I click on the browser back button I want to send it back to the homepage which is the "/" route. How can I implement this feature in Next js?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69569682/15814542