# Want to have an event handler for the browser's back button with next.js <13>

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to listen browser back in NextJS 13.

As for NextJS before 13, this article good, which uses `beforePopState`, but it seems that in ver13, this function is not implemented.

[Want to have an event handler for the browser's back button with next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932918/want-to-have-an-event-handler-for-the-browsers-back-button-with-next-js)

Can somebody solve this problem in ver 13? Thanks!